# StackOverflow on Cypher Query with SDN

Tags: neo4j, repository, sdn

I'm using Neo4J 2.1.5 with SDN 3.2.0.RELEASE and Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE

One repository contains a derived query:

```
Landscape getLandscapeByuuid(String landscapeUUID);
```

Intermittently (and it is -- some calls to this method return the appropriate object, some generate the error below, without any changes to the database between calls), I get a loooong Error stack trace, which starts:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getAllRelationshipsOfType(NodeImpl.java:181) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getRelationships(NodeImpl.java:241) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.PersistenceCache.nodeGetRelationships(PersistenceCache.java:200) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.CacheLayer.nodeListRelationships(CacheLayer.java:451) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodeGetRelationships(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:903) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.nodeGetRelationships(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:358) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeGetRelationships(OperationsFacade.java:174) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getRelationships(NodeProxy.java:170) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getRelationships(NodeProxy.java:161) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getRelationships(NodeProxy.java:76) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.getRelationships(RelationshipHelper.java:182) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessor.loadRelationshipEntities(RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:133) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessor.getValue(RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:120) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.getValue(DefaultEntityState.java:97) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:90) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$2.doWithAssociation(SourceStateTransmitter.java:61) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesFrom(SourceStateTransmitter.java:57) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityFetchHandler.fetchValue(Neo4jEntityFetchHandler.java:75) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityFetchHandler.fetch(Neo4jEntityFetchHandler.java:68) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl$1.doWithAssociation(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:135) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.cascadeFetch(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:125) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.loadEntity(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:114) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:104) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:192) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.createEntityFromState(Neo4jTemplate.java:224) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.GraphBackedEntityIterableWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(GraphBackedEntityIterableWrapper.java:41) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.GraphBackedEntityIterableWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(GraphBackedEntityIterableWrapper.java:27) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IterableWrapper$MyIteratorWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(IterableWrapper.java:57) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:382) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:461) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessor.getValue(RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:122) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.getValue(DefaultEntityState.java:97) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:90) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$2.doWithAssociation(SourceStateTransmitter.java:61) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

(full dump at http://pastebin.com/k9iMc0cU)

Relevant domain object is Landscape -- It is very simple. I've included its superclasses and inherited interfaces also. The important question I have is... why is the above error intermittent -- what I normally see is that the first two calls to that method will generate the error, with he third and subsequent ones succeeding... some caching issues in neo4j, maybe?

```
public class Landscape extends GenericPublication {

    private String comments;

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }


}

public interface IPublication {

    public Set<Syndication> getSyndications();

    public String getUuid();

    public void setComments(String comments);

    public void setName(String name);

    public void setSyndications(Set<Syndication> syndications);

    public void setUuid(String uuid);

}

@NodeEntity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class GenericPublication implements IPublication {

    @Fetch
    @XmlElement
    @RelatedTo(type = "SYNDICATES_TO", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    Set<ArticleCollection> articleCollections = new HashSet<ArticleCollection>();

    @Fetch
    @XmlElement
    String comments;

    @Fetch
    @XmlElement
    String name;

    @GraphId
    @Fetch
    Long nodeId;

    @Fetch
    @RelatedToVia(type = "SYNDICATES_TO", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    Set<Syndication> syndications;

    @Fetch
    @XmlElement
    @Indexed
    String uuid;

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<Syndication> getSyndications() {
        return syndications;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSyndications(Set<Syndication> syndications) {
        this.syndications = syndications;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "SYNDICATES_TO")
public class Syndication {

    @GraphId
    Long nodeId;

    @Fetch
    @StartNode
    @Indexed
    ArticleCollection articleCollection;

    @Fetch
    @EndNode
    @Indexed
    GenericPublication publication;

    @Fetch
    @Indexed
    String uuid;

    @Fetch
    Set<String> categories;

    public Set<String> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Set<String> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public Long getNodeId() {
        return nodeId;
    }

    public void setNodeId(Long nodeId) {
        this.nodeId = nodeId;
    }

    public ArticleCollection getArticleCollection() {
        return articleCollection;
    }

    public void setArticleCollection(ArticleCollection articleCollection) {
        this.articleCollection = articleCollection;
    }

    public GenericPublication getPublication() {
        return publication;
    }

    public void setPublication(GenericPublication publication) {
        this.publication = publication;
    }

}
```

Any ideas what's the problem here? This is such a straightforward use-case that I'm bemused where to look...

Comment: FYI I also tried an explicit Cypher version of the derived query: `@Query("MATCH (landscape:Landscape{uuid:{landscapeUUID}}) RETURN landscape")
 Landscape retrieveLandscapeByUUID(@Param("landscapeUUID") String landscapeUUID);` -- that also intermittently generates the same error, so I'm guessing its something deeper down.. ideas?

Comment: Without looking deeper into this, I suspect it might be something to do with dense nodes vs nodes with a few relationships. Could you try to debug and see which nodes this happens on? See if it has many relationships? It would be useful to extract this into a test and submit an issue

Comment: You have to capitalize the property-name: getLandscapeByUuid

Comment: You should share the code of your domain objects too.